# .NET app randomly fails on Lotus Notes session opening

Tags: c#, .net, com, lotus-notes, lotus

We created a .NET application that collects data from IBM (Lotus) Notes. It connects to Notes via COM objects (Lotus Domino Objects).

In general, it works and do all the operations we need, but then, after some hours of work, the app stops working. I mean, it kinda freezes and stops doing any job. It happens on different databases in unpredictable time, so I couldn't find any regularity

The last log message we got from the app either:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010105):  Creating an
>   instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {29131539-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7} from the IClassFactory failed 
>   due to the following error: 80010105 The server threw an exception.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)).    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)    at
>   MyMethod(NotesServerConfig notesServerConfig, String mailBox) in
>   D:...\MyClass.cs:line 164

or

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040FA1):  Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80040FA1    at Domino.ISession.Initialize(String
>   pPassword)    at MyMethod(NotesServerConfig notesServerConfig, String
>   mailBox) in D:...\MyClass.cs:line 164

The fact that they both have link to the line 164 of MyClass, which is just an invocation of a session's constructor:

```
var session = new NotesSession();
```

My real app works as a Windows Service via Topshelf, so there are a lot of code in it since the project has became pretty big already. So let me try to put here a simplified version without any extra code and 3rd party libraries to show how I use Lotus Domino Objects:

```
using Domino;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace LotusTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int _maxClientReCreateAttempts = 10;

        private const string _password = "qwerty";
        private const string _server = "test.server.ru";

        private static readonly List<string> _dbNames = new List<string>
        {
            "mail\\test1", "mail\\test2", "mail\\test3"
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var dbName in _dbNames)
            {
                var folders = GetFolders(dbName);
                foreach (var folder in folders)
                {
                    var mailSubjects = GetEmailSubjects(folder, dbName);
                    foreach (var mailSubject in mailSubjects)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Mail {mailSubject} in {folder}, db: {dbName}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static List<string> GetFolders(string dbName)
        {
            var result = new List<string>();

            var session = new NotesSession();
            session.Initialize(_password);
            var db = session.GetDatabase(_server, dbName, false);

            if (db == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Can't read the database: {dbName}");
                return result;
            }

            foreach (var view in db.Views)
            {
                if (!view.IsFolder) { continue; }
                result.Add(view.Name);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static List<string> GetEmailSubjects(string viewName, string dbName)
        {
            var result = new List<string>();

            var session = new NotesSession();
            session.Initialize(_password);

            var db = session.GetDatabase(_server, dbName, false);

            if (db == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Can't read the database: {dbName}");
                return result;
            }

            var cv = db.GetView(viewName);
            if (cv == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Can't read '{viewName}' folder of '{dbName}' database");
                return result;
            }

            return ReadFolder(cv, session, dbName, viewName);            
        }

        private static List<string> ReadFolder(NotesView cv, NotesSession session, string folder, string mailBox)
        {
            var result = new List<string>();
            var doc = cv.GetFirstDocument();

            int i = 0;
            int errCount = 0;
            bool lastGetWithError = false;
            int totalAmount = cv?.AllEntries?.Count ?? 0;

            int clientReCreateAttempts = 0;

            while (doc != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!lastGetWithError)
                    {
                        result.Add(doc.GetItemValue("Subject")[0]);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Folder: {folder}, processed: {i + 1 - errCount} of {totalAmount}");   
                    }

                    doc = cv.GetNextDocument(doc);
                    lastGetWithError = false;
                }
                catch (COMException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error on reading folder {folder} of mailbox {mailBox}.\r\n{ex}");
                    if (clientReCreateAttempts > _maxClientReCreateAttempts)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Reading mail doc error: ", ex);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine($"Trying to re-create Notes session");
                    session = new NotesSession();
                    clientReCreateAttempts++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error on reading folder {folder} of mailbox {mailBox}.\r\n{ex}");
                    lastGetWithError = true;
                }
                finally
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

So, according to freezing - maybe it's just a bug in my exception handling. But there are a couple of things I wanna ask:

1. Is it possible to understand what exactly happens behind those
   `0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)` and `0x80040FA1` errors?
2. Based on the code I've put here, do I use NotesSession and other Lotus COM objects right? I
   mean, do I need to dispose/release/close the session (or other objects) somehow after I
   make some operation etc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you connect to a Domino server, and you get errors, look in the log.nsf database on the server. It might be some timeout on the server, but it might also be some network problem.

Comment: Domino COM objects use local NRPC, so it would be the log.nsf on the client if you are not running this application on the Domino server.

Comment: Are you running on 64 bits? If so, I'm not entirely surprised. The methods that return design object collections (e.g. db.Views) were known to be unreliable on win64 in the past. In fact, using the Domino COM objects on win64 was not supported by IBM. There was a technote that I'm sure I've referred to in some other answers here on StackOverflow.  This was 8 to 10 years ago, so things might have gotten better since then. Your crash is while establishing the NotesSession, but the root cause could be something else entirely.

Comment: @D.Bugger Thanks, I tried to check out log.nsf for the corresponding period of time and didn't find out some serious errors. Once before one of the crashes I've seen `Error in SECKFMDefaultPromptHandler: func=25: Unknown security function code`, but it didn't occur later again so I'm not sure it's the main problem.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Thank you! Yes, you're right. My app is built for x64, and Lotus COM object is connected via DllSurrogate in a registry. First, I was trying to make my app x86, but it gave me unpredictable `OutOfMemory` crashes. `db.Views` is now working on x64 by the way. Do you think that those problems will keep happening anyhow while I'm still on Win64?

Comment: This can all be the same underlying problem.  A notorious issue with out-of-process servers is them not terminating when they should.  After you get a crash like this, use Task Manager, Processes tab and look at running instances.  Seeing dozens of them still active is the cue, your program will fail like this when kernel memory pool gets low.

Comment: It's really hard to say what problems you're going to run into in Win64. On the last project I worked on with it, we gave up on it and reverted to x86 for all access to the Lotus classes, but that was  8 to 10 years ago and was probably on top of a Notes 7 client installation if I recall correctly, and I'm pretty sure that we spun off a new task (not a thread) for each mailbox scan (this was an archiving product) to avoid having objects hanging out forever. But this was a long time ago, and I may be mixing up different projects with different technologies in my memory.

Comment: I had the same problem and the issue (from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80010105 The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)).) The solution was to right click on the .dll file and to unblock it (click the checkbox) , in the General tab, at the end, where Security is mentioned.